# How can I remove markers then add markers to my map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to clear my map of all markers on function call and load new markers.

On stack I found this piece of code, which I executed when a button was clicked. It did not clear my markers:

```
//clear markers
        google.maps.Map.prototype.clearMarkers = function() {
            for(var i=0; i < this.markers.length; i++){
                this.markers[i].setMap(null);
            }
            this.markers = new Array();
        };
```

After Clearing Markers How would I load new markers?

My Google map is set up like this:

```
 var locations = [['21st Amendment Brewery', 37.7824175, -122.3925921] ,['Allagash Brewing Company', 43.702697, -70.317975] ,['Anchor Brewing Company', 37.763487, -122.401367] ,['Anheuser-Busch', 38.5986606, -90.208751] ,['Ayinger Brewery', , ] ,['Bass Brewery', 52.8045853, -1.6281372] ,['Bear Republic Brewery', 38.6040452, -122.8599961] ,['Boston Beer Company', 42.314449, -71.103365] ,['Boulevard Brewing Company', 39.0821348, -94.5966532] ,['Brasserie des Franches-Montagnes', 47.2542808, 7.0025782] ,['Breckenridge Brewery', 39.723597, -105.000614] ,['Brewery Ommegang', 42.6818046, -74.9254739] ,['Brooklyn Brewery', 40.721535, -73.95745] ,['Brouwerij Artois', 50.8870692, 4.7025108] ,['Brouwerij Huyghe', 50.99832, 3.79404] ,['Buffalo Bills Brewery', 37.6738157, -122.0813029] ,['Butternuts Beer and Ale', 42.6290648, -75.1854868] ,['Caldera Brewing', 42.184409, -122.663147] ,['Cervecera Cuauhtmoc-Moctezuma', 25.6375417, -100.2946801] ,['Clipper City Brewing Company', 39.230827, -76.6751309] ,['Coors Brewing Company', 39.759876, -105.219026] ,['Cricket Hill Brewing Company', 40.872566, -74.296359] ,['D.G. Yuengling and Son', 40.6999592, -76.1747169] ,['Dogfish Head Craft Brewery', 38.770622, -75.310893] ,['DuClaw Brewing Company', 39.496656, -76.329843] ,['Erie Brewing Company', 42.111185, -80.112978] ,['Evolution Craft Brewing Company', 38.4622609, -75.5741469] ,['Firestone Walker Brewing Company', 35.595325, -120.693728] ,['Flying Dog Brewery', 39.361926, -77.424677] ,['Fordham Brewing Company', 39.1540034, -75.4883626] ,['Founders Brewing Company', 42.958468, -85.673516] ,['Fulton Brewing Company', 44.9849423, -93.2790206] ,['Goose Island Beer Company', 41.887107, -87.6720969] ,['Gordon Biersch Brewing', 37.354139, -121.89286] ,['Grand Canyon Brewing Company', 35.249954, -112.1891462] ,['Great Divide Brewing Company', 39.753646, -104.9884698] ,['Green Flash Brewing Company', 32.905722, -117.176517] ,['Grupo Modelo S.A. de C.V.', 19.422447, -99.209758] ,['Guinness', 53.34309, -6.290799] ,['Harpoon Brewery', 43.512997, -72.401527] ,['Heavy Seas', 39.230827, -76.6751309] ,['Heineken International', , ] ,['Hoppin Frog Brewery', 41.0245928, -81.4677107] ,['Jacob Leinenkugel Brewing Company', 44.943321, -91.3953049] ,['Lagunitas Brewing Company', 38.272435, -122.662346] ,['Magic Hat Brewing Company', 44.428405, -73.213148] ,['Maui Brewing Company', 20.972149, -156.677334] ,['Mendocino Brewing Company', 38.9734335, -123.1162429] ,['MillerCoors Brewing Company', 43.044464, -87.962562] ,['Narragansett Brewing Company', 41.8190249, -71.4097368] ,['New Belgium Brewing', 40.593415, -105.066874] ,['North Coast Brewing Company', 39.446471, -123.806238] ,['Old Dominion Brewing Company', 39.1540034, -75.4883626] ,['Oskar Blues Brewery', 40.139056, -105.121887] ,['Pabst Brewing Company', 29.4497864, -98.5386319] ,['Port Brewing Company', 33.141417, -117.150076] ,['Port City Brewing Company', 38.8081958, -77.1014693] ,['RJ Rockers Brewing Company', 34.948639, -81.935726] ,['Rock Art Brewery', 44.557791, -72.608085] ,['Rogue Ales', 44.620173, -124.0520565] ,['Schneider Weisse', 48.91755, 11.87451] ,['Scottish & Newcastle Breweries', 55.954155, -3.202774] ,['Shipyard Brewing', 43.6618784, -70.2489402] ,['Sierra Nevada Brewing Company', 39.7246028, -121.8157154] ,['Sixpoint Craft Ales', 40.6739317, -74.0119473] ,['Sleeman Breweries Ltd.', 43.4870365, -80.2067709] ,['Smuttynose Brewing Co.', 43.032502, -70.7947688] ,['Southern Tier Brewing Company', 42.088931, -79.350342] ,['Spaten-Franziskaner-Bräu', 48.14501, 11.55419] ,['Staatliches Hofbräuhaus (Hofbräu München)', 48.1373073, 11.580357] ,['Stone Brewing Company', 33.115682, -117.119552] ,['Stoudts Brewery', 40.2422441, -76.0540026] ,['Sudwerk', , ] ,['Surly Brewing Company', 45.04285, -93.324557] ,['The Bronx Brewery', 40.80828, -73.930669] ,['The Duck-Rabbit Craft Brewery', 35.600267, -77.597058] ,['The Lost Abbey', 33.141417, -117.150076] ,['The Saint Louis Brewery', 38.632968, -90.209769] ,['Tröegs Brewing Company', 40.304, -76.643519] ,['Unibroue', 45.466125, -73.290924] ,['Union Craft Brewing Company', 39.331938, -76.641971] ,['Victory Brewing Company', 40.0061038, -75.6941546] ,['Wells and Young&#39;s Brewing Company', 52.132011, -0.481523] ,['Weyerbacher Brewing Company', 40.673181, -75.224926] ,['Widmer Brothers Brewing', 45.540795, -122.675594] ,['Yards Brewing Company', 39.962616, -75.136253]  

        ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]);  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map
      });



      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));

      bounds.extend(position);

    } //end for loop


    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to remove the markers again, you need to keep them somewhere - so you can then loop though them when you want to remove them again. An array is a convenient way of doing that.

```
//create a (possibly global) array to store the markers
var markers = [];

...
//create the markers

for(...) {
     marker = new google.maps.Marker(...);
     markers.push(marker);
}

....
//destroy the markers

for (var i = markers.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
     markers[i].setMap(null);
     delete markers[i];
}
```

Comment: Can I change my locations array to a marker array? and where would I put those for loops you suggested?

Comment: Its one way to do it. First loop is the one that creates the markers, the second is the one that removes them all. So whereever you want to create and destroy markers....

Comment: awesome, one more questions what is the format for markers when setting marker = to something. Also How do I set the message balloons to those markers? My code now is setting balloons to them

Comment: However you create markers now. You just need to add the `markers.push(marker);` line almost anywhere in the your current for loop eg, right before the `bounds.extend(...)` line.

Comment: I added markers.push(marker); right after bounds extend(...); and when I loaded my map it showed me a map with no markers.

Comment: Did you check the error console? maybe you have a typo. or the markers variable is not in scope.

Comment: I get this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: markers is not defined

Comment: Yep, it seems to be a scope issue. You havent put the `var markers = ...` in the right place.

Comment: any suggestions where to put it?

Comment: Somewhere where its in scope everywhere you need it. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
{
markers[i].setMap(null);
}
markers.length = 0;
```

First remove all the markers like the snippet above. Then again you can use

```
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map
  });
```

to create new markers

Comment: Not sure what you mean by remove the brackets?

Comment: For some reason I read brackets not markers, I will give this a try

Comment: I get this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: markers is not defined 

When I run the part of your code for removing the markers